# Word for non-monetary price

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

Is there a word or phrase or expression for something that you ask in return for a product or service, when it is something other than money?

And what is the verb that goes with it when someone “pays” the non-monetary price?

(I can’t think of anything else other than “a favour in return”, with possibly the verb “to do a favour in return for the product”; or “a kickback”, which sounds fishier than I would like, and I don’t know what verb goes with that.)

Comment: Umm - we just use the word "price" anyway. It doesn't *have* to imply money changed hands. That's General Reference, I think.

Comment: I think all the answers so far are simply missing the point. Even if you're *bartering/trading/swapping/etc.* you still have to give a name to the *amount/quality of whatever whatever you want in return for your product/service*. What you ask for is still your ***price***, whatever units it's rendered in.

Comment: See [_value, price, worth,_ and _cost_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/valueworthpricecost.pdf).

Comment: @FumbleFingers- I think the OP is a bit ambiguous as to what he's looking for. The title asks for a "price", the first paragraph asks for '*something* you ask for in return' and the third paragraph suggests that *kickback* or *favor* is close to what he's after and then wants a verb. I think *price* is appropriate for the title.  I think *consideration* works for a *what-you-ask-for noun* and I think *trade* or *barter* works for a verb. (remunerate and remuneration also work but they are probably too high-falutin' for normal use)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree that *price* is the correct word, but I don't find a satisfactory definition in a freely available source.

Comment: @Matt: OED - *B5 fig. What it costs to obtain some advantage; that which is given, surrendered, or undergone, for the sake of something else. Freq. in phr. at a price; also at any price: whatever it may cost, whatever loss or disadvantage is or may be entailed.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers aye, but that's not *free* as in gratis. OED is shaky ground for GR. [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/price?q=price) doesn't have that definition (for some reason). Although, now I look, [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/price?s=t) does have it.

Comment: @Matt: Yes, that last definition there is obviously what we're thinking of.

Comment: @Jim The question is not ambiguous. The problem is that it's two questions, not one. (1) What do you call the "price" of something when it's non-monetary? (2) what verb do you use instead of "paying" when "paying" such a "price"?

Answer (score 10):

The legal term is *consideration*. It encompasses anything of value in a trade: money, property, or services. This is a word you can use when "money" is not appropriate. *Trading* is the general term for exchange of consideration. For more information: *[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consideration)*.

Answer (score 7):

• *[in kind](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/payment_in_kind)* refers to “In the form of goods and service rather than money”; for example, “He received payment in kind.”
• *[swop](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/swop)*, *[swap](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/swap#English)*, and *[barter](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/barter#Noun)* refer to “exchange [of] goods or services without involving money”
• *[quid pro quo](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quid_pro_quo)* also refers to a form of barter:  “This for that; giving something to receive something else ; something equivalent; something in return” or “An equal exchange”.  *Eg*,  “We had no money so we had to live by quid pro quo.”

Comment: As is implied by HMRC's (re-)interpretation of [There is no statutory definition for NICs of the term ‘payment in kind’](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/manuals/nimmanual/nim13171.htm), *payment in kind* was understood by the original legislators to mean *benefits which could not easily be "monetised" by the recipient*. As I recall, there was some sharp practice before they made that ruling - companies paying their staff in gold Krugerrands, for example!

Comment: This entire answer is good, but +1 esp. for _quid pro quo_.

Answer (score 5):

I would use *[compensation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/compensation#Noun)* and *[compensate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/compensate#Verb)*.

Answer (score 3):

I think the word you're looking for is [barter](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/barter).

The verb that would go with it would be bartered. Eg. James bartered a scooter with John for his broken push bike.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the word *trade*:

> [***trade***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trade):  3. An instance of bartering items in exchange for one another.

In your instance I would ask for something *in trade* for my item/service. The verb is *to trade*.  He *traded* me a pickup truck for my old TV.

There are lots of instances on craigslist.com saying '*Willing to trade*' X for Y

Answer (score 1):

You could ask for *remuneration*. To [*remunerate* is](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/remunerate) "to pay (a person) a suitable equivalent in return for goods provided, services rendered, or losses incurred." That suitable equivalent is not necessarily cash.

You could also asked to be *compensated for your time or service.* The compensation does not have to be in the form of money.

Answer (score 1):

In vernacular:

> I mow his lawn, he gives me free cable. It's a fair **trade**. It **costs** me all of an hour a week. He **lives up to his end** of the **bargain**. If he ever doesn't **make-good** or **follow-through**, then I'll cancel our **deal**.

Or:

> Sure, I can pull a few strings for you... But, it'll **cost** you. And, you'd better be **good for it**.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also use "in exchange" e.g I fixed his videogame console in exchange for a baseball game ticket.

Here, there is a form of trade/barter/non-monetary exchange implied and it is just simple and straight forward. And the concept of trading, at heart, is any form of exchange.

Answer (score 0):

***non-monetary payment***

Firstly, *price* is not defined as necessarily monetary, though it usually is understood to be monetary value of an item. Perhaps, that's the price you pay for using a flexible language like English. See:

> [Price](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price) (Wikipedia)
>   In ordinary usage, price is the quantity of payment or compensation given by one party to another in return for goods or services.
>   In modern economies, prices are generally expressed in units of some form of currency. (For commodities, they are expressed as currency per unit weight of the commodity, e.g. euros per kilogram.) Although prices could be quoted as quantities of other goods or services this sort of barter exchange is rarely seen. Prices are sometimes quoted in terms of vouchers such as trading stamps and air miles. In some circumstances, cigarettes have been used as currency, for example in prisons, in times of hyperinflation, and in some places during World War 2. In the black economy, barter is also relatively common.

and

> [price](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/price.html) (BusinessDictionary)
>   A value that will purchase a definite quantity, weight, or other measure of a good or service.

However, if we are looking for a term that expressly excludes monetary payment, and want to be unambiguous about it, the only option seems to be ***non-monetary payment***, as in "...*non-monetary payment is the best way to compensate authors for the use of their words and ideas.*"

Answer (score 0):

When you avail a *service* or *product* and intend to know its **non-monetary price**, you ask for its *worth* or *cost*.

Here, *cost* doesn't necessarily have to do with money. Cost can be reflected in other terms as well such as man-hour, effort, services in return etc.

***For Eg:***

*What is this (fill-in-the-blank) worth?*

*What is it gonna cost me?*

Personally, if I understand you correctly I would use

> What do I owe you?